# How do I select records less than 1 year old?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This should be a fairly simple question but I know very little about SQL. I have a database which has the following fields:

- `client_id`
- `scheduled_amount`
- `deposit_amount`
- `message_code_id`
- `note_text`
- `system_date`

Now I wish to select all the records that are less than 1 year old from when the SQL statement is run. I know I should use `DateDiff`, anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
select *
from MyTable
where MyDate > DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate())
```

Answer (score 3):

TRY

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE SYSTEM_DATE > DATEADD(YYYY, -1, GETDATE())
```

(UNTESTED)

Answer (score 1):

```
select ... from ... where YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(YOURDATE) = 1
```

Comment: for db2:  ```WHERE YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(YourDateField) = 1```